# Is there any academical research that pertains to CTA importance and efficiency?

Tags: research, call-to-action

I want to find some very respectable research that unveils the importance and efficiency of calls to action.

Comment: [Not academical work, but an interesting read](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/good-call-to-action-buttons/)

Comment: Is it possible that you could expand upon your question? No offense, but as stated, it seems like you want the community to Google for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great article on how to create unbeatable Call to actions:

http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/compelling-call-to-action.html

I think the basics to remember are make the wording concise yet compelling, and make the button attractive and obvious.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [Eyetracking Web Usability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321498364) by Nielse as a starting point to your research.
Basically call to action buttons tend to have one of the following properties:

- Different color
- Larger than regular buttons
- They are the only button in the page
- They are aligned differently
- They have a different icon
- ...

This is made on purpose so that once you enter the page and your eyes start scanning the page, that button will be the first thing you notice.
Sorry I can not point you to a specific research paper. Just be careful when you reach to conclusions after reading some blog posts, articles...
I've seen some interesting discussions around the web that just changing one button to one color increased the clicks by X%.
Keep in mind that all this depends on the context and lots of external variables.